# Power BI dynamic index table with filters

Tags: powerbi

I try to get a dynamic index table in Power BI to later be used to sort a stacked area chart. Importantly, I need it to take current filters into account.

The idea is to get something like:

```
Product   | Index
Product 1 | 1
Product 3 | 2
Product 4 | 3
Product 2 | 4
```

I can count product with filters a measure:

```
sum2 = COUNTX(table_name, [Product])
```

But unfortunately I can't sort Product column by a measure.

All examples I found have the names of the categories entered manually which is not what I'm looking for. Moreover, the filtering part is important to me.

Comment: FYI, it's not possible to create a calculated column that responds to slicers or other report filters.

Comment: What egxacly do you want to sort (for what purpose)? In stacked chart under [...] you have an option sort axies by Column from Axies or Values [measure]

Comment: @msta42a, I try to sort legend. I'd like the chart to display biggest Product at bottom and smaller stacked in order of size. That's why I'd like it to be responsive to filters.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, that's what I'm afraid of. If that's really not possible to be done in Power BI I'll add the index table in the data processing step.